# Open keyboard in Android recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, keyboard

So I am taking the CompTIA A+ certification courses and on one of the sections about radio firmware, they say after placing `Update.zip` in the root of the SD card to boot into recovery then press Alt+S and let the update finish.

The only way I know how would be to use the up and down volume keys and choose Update from Sd Card then press power.

I could only find the following reference to using Alt+S, it is [a guide from the XDA Developers website from 2009](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-adb-fastboot-and-nandroid-for-noobs.532719/post-4066552):

> **[GUIDE] Fastboot for Noobs**
>
> **Fastboot**
>
> Things you need:
>
> New SPL - Download
> New Radio - Download
> Your Current ROM - CyanogenMod 3.6
> SD Card Reader
> Rooted G1 Phone
> Computer
> USB Cable
> Patience
>
> ---
>
> **Install Radio FIRST**
>
> Download the Radio Update
> Rename it to update.zip
> Remove your SD Card from your phone and place it in your SD Card Reader
> Put the update.zip at the root of your SDcard (root = not in any folder)
> Insert your sdcard back into the phone
> Turn off your phone (Hold power and press Power Off)
> Hold the Home button and then press the power button (Keep holding power)
> You will now enter recovery
> **Open up your keyboard and press Alt-S**
> Let it finish the update
> When done reboot by pressing Home and Back
> You should be able to access your Home screen (If its stuck on the Google G1 screen dont panic, just remove your battery for now)

My question would be: HOW would I open the keyboard in recovery mode? I tried a keyboard connected via OTG cable and could get it to move up and down and select, but Alt+S did nothing.

Now full disclosure, I DID NOT have any `Update.zip` on my SD card. I was assuming I would get an error. The only device I have available at this time is my Samsung Galaxy S20 and I can't find the right file for my firmware.

Is this process outdated? Does it require that phone be rooted with a custom recovery? Without more info, the first sentence of this post makes no sense. If anyone can shed a light on this would be great.

Comment: modern equivalent... try to find right keys ;) [Xiaomi Qin F21 Pro Touch](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tools-mod-scripts-mlgmxyysds-qin-f21-pro-unlock-tool.4368277/page-4)

Answer (score 2):

The instruction "boot into recovery then press Alt+S and let the update finish." is strange I have never seen a stock recovery ROM with a possibility to activate an on-screen keyboard. The second problem is that on-screen keyboards usually do not contain an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

The only explanation is that the instruction does not refer to the on-screen keyboard:

In the early days of Android there were a few phones like the Google G1 (alias HTC Dream) which had built-in hardware keyboard:

[image: HTC Dream image from Wikipedia by "Akela NDE"]

It seems like the manual for firmware update was written for such a device as the instruction does only make sense in case there is a hardware keyboard available.

Because of the amazing success of the iPhone and it's pure touch screen based UI Android phones with hardware keyboards were only present before 2010 like the [HTC Dream (2008)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream) or [Motorola Droid/Milestone "Stone" (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Droid). Later nearly all Android phones only had a touch screen with on-screen keyboard (with a very few exceptions like the [BlackBerry KeyOne (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_KeyOne) - but those devices were never a commercial success).

As your manual can only work for phones with a hardware keyboard it can be considered historical and no longer relevant. Seems like the people responsible for keeping the question up-to-date have missed this question for a long time.